# Obtain span title using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html

I have this span and I want to get the 7 mins out of it using beautifulsoup?

```
<span>In current traffic: 7 mins</span>
```

I have tried

```
res = soup.find('span')
title = res['In current traffic']
print 'Current Listeners:', title.text
```

But does not work

***EDIT**

my acctual code is below

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2


url = "https://maps.google.com.au/maps?saddr=A6&daddr=A6&hl=en&ll=-33.877613,151.039867&spn=0.081236,0.083599&sll=-33.869204,151.034546&sspn=0.081244,0.083599&geocode=FYSu-v0d2KMACQ%3BFbp0-_0dJKoACQ&mra=ls&t=m&z=14&layer=t"

content = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)

res = soup.find('span')
title = res['In current traffic']
print 'Current Listeners:', res.text
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're already receiving it:

```
>>> res = soup.find('span')
>>> res
<span>In current traffic: 7 mins</span>
>>>
```

To access the data, check `res.text`:

```
>>> res.text
u'In current traffic: 7 mins'
```

To find the part you wanted, you can use find:

```
pos = res.text.find(': ')
res.text[pos+2:]
```

So, your full code should be:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2


url = "https://maps.google.com.au/maps?saddr=A6&daddr=A6&hl=en&ll=-33.877613,151.039867&spn=0.081236,0.083599&sll=-33.869204,151.034546&sspn=0.081244,0.083599&geocode=FYSu-v0d2KMACQ%3BFbp0-_0dJKoACQ&mra=ls&t=m&z=14&layer=t"

content = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)

div = soup.find('div', {'class':'altroute-rcol altroute-aux'}) #get the div where it's located
span = div.find('span')
pos = span.text.find(': ')
print 'Current Listeners:', span.text[pos+2:]
```

Result:

```
Current Listeners: 7 min
```

**Edit**: updated my code to work with your link.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry, Martijn's answer answered the question completely.

Comment: sorry, but it does not work, please find above my edit. I am getting this from a website with many spans, sorry for the edit

Comment: 7mins is a dynamic value

Comment: i feel like a noob, i get the following error   File "traffic.py", line 13, in <module>
    print 'Current Listeners:', res.text[pos+2:]
NameError: name 'res' is not defined

Comment: Ouch sorry that was my mistake, fixed now. It supposed to be `span.text`, not `res.text`. Hahaha

Comment: @GamesBrainiac Hey i won!

Answer (score 1):

`res` is a `<span>` tag with text. You cannot have BeautifulSoup break up that text any further, the whole text is *one* unit:

```
>>> res.text
u'In current traffic: 7 mins'
```

Use string methods to get the part you want:

```
>>> res.text.rsplit(':', 1)[-1].strip()
'7 mins'
```

The `res[...]` syntax would give you access to HTML attributes on a tag, but the `<span>` has no attributes at all.